# How to pass a parameter from one component to another in Formik?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have my Formik like below:

```
<Formik
  validationSchema={schema}
  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  initialValues={this.state}
  values={this.state}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
 >
 {({
    handleSubmit,
    handleChange,
    handleBlur,
    values,
    touched,
    isValid,
    errors
  }) => (
  .....
  <Form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
   <Form.Row>
    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="validationFormik01">
     <Form.Control
       type="text"
       placeholder="Username"
       name="username"
       value={values.username}
       onChange={handleChange}
       isInvalid={touched.username && errors.username}
     />
    <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
     {errors.username}
    </Form.Control.Feedback>
   </Form.Group>
  </Form.Row>
  .....
  <ShowPassword /> // ---> the new component
</Formik>
```

And then I have created another component with input and a button for password in order to toggle it on/off like this:

```
class ShowPassword extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        active: false,
        type: 'password',
    };
    this.toggleButton = this.toggleButton.bind(this);
}
toggleButton() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({active: !currentState});
    if(currentState) {
        this.setState({type: 'password'});
    } else {
        this.setState({type: 'text'})
    }
}

render() {
    return(
      <Form.Row>
       <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="validationFormik05">
        <InputGroup >
          <Form.Control
            type={this.state.type}
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            name="confirmpassword"
            value={this.state.confirmpassword}
          isInvalid={touched.confirmpassword && errors.confirmpassword} //--->this one
           />
          <InputGroup.Append>
            <button className="showPassword" onClick={this.toggleButton} type="button" 
             variant="outline-secondary">
             <i className={this.state.active ? 'pi pi-eye' : 'pi pi-eye-slash'} aria-hidden="true"> 
             </i>
            </button>
          </InputGroup.Append>
         <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
            {errors.confirmpassword} // ---> this one
         </Form.Control.Feedback>
                </InputGroup>
            </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>
     )
   }
 }
```

So the thing is that there are some parameters in the `<ShowPassword />` component that are not defined because of the scope. Is there a way to pass these parameters from the parent `Formik` into the child component?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`connect`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/connect).

As the docs says

> `connect()` is a higher-order component (HoC) that allows you to hook anything into Formik's context. It is used internally to construct  and , but you can use it to build out new components as your needs change.

When wrapping your component with `connect`

```
export default connect(ShowPassword)
```

You will receive `this.props.formik` which have all of formik's props.

e.g.

```
<Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
    {this.props.formik.errors.confirmpassword} // ---> this one
</Form.Control.Feedback>
```

and

```
export default connect(ShowPassword)
```

Comment: thanks but still it says "Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined". Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: `export default connect(ShowPassword)` are your doing this? You need to wrap your component with `connect`

Comment: Yeah outside the `class ShowPassword extends React.Component{}` I just did what you said, `export default connect(ShowPassword)`

Comment: Try this `this.props.formik && this.props.formik.errors.confirmpassword`. Maybe in the initial render, the formik props isn't defined. Also make sure that `ShowPassword` is inside the `Formik` component, if it's outside, it will be undefined

Comment: Yeah I think the formik props isn't defined.

Comment: Is `ShowPassword` inside `Formik` component?

Comment: well I just started learning React so forgive me if I don't know some basics. The structure goes like this. In the .js file I got two separate `classes`, one with the `Formik`- registration Form and the component with the `input`-child component and I just use it inside the other `class` where the `Formik` is rendered.

Comment: You need something like `<Formik> <ShowPassword /></Formik>`